# how to separate and display select option data?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have two forms. `form1`'s content is a choice option filled by name, matricule, and salary, and a button validate, which hides `form1` and displays `form2`. I want when I click on the button, the contents of `select` to separate and show like this:

```
name:
registration number :
salary :
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#hide").click(function() {
    let name1 = $('#name').text();
    let matricule1 = $('#matricule').text();
    let salary1 = $('#salary').text();

    $('#nam').text(name1);
    $('#mat').text(matricule1);
    $('#sal').text(salary1);

    $("#form1").hide();
    $("#form2").show();
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="form1">
  <div class="form-group col-md-3">
    <select class="form-control">
      <option>
        <div id="name">imad</div>
        <div id="matricule">22</div>
        <div id="salary">6000</div>
      </option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group col-md-offset-5 ">
    <button class="btn btn-success " id="hide">valider</button>
  </div>
</div>

<!--form 2-->
<div id="form2">
  <h4>name : <span id="nam"></span></h4>
  <h4>matricule : <span id="mat"></span></h4>
  <h4>salary : <span id="sal"></span></h4>
</div>
```

Comment: It's not clear exactly what you're trying to do, however I can tell you that having any HTML within an `option` element is invalid. If you need to layout the data in a select like that you'll need to use a custom library, such as Select2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Rory said, you cannot have `HTML` within an option element, this is invalid. Use a custom drop-down select library (some examples of such are here: https://www.sitepoint.com/13-jquery-selectboxdrop-down-plugins/)

Now, if you know the format of the data you are using to populate the `select option values` with (you are getting data from server side, etc.), you could then format the data on the client side with some sort of separator to create a chained together `option value` for the 3 different fields, like I've done in the example below using a dash (`-`). You could then split the string value of the `option selected`, and parse it out to individual text fields. Again, this is all dependent on how you get and format the data within the `select` element.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#hide").click(function() {

    let selectOption = $('.form-control').val();
    let optionSplits = selectOption.split('-');

    let name1 = optionSplits[0];
    let matricule1 = optionSplits[1];
    let salary1 = optionSplits[2];

    $('#nam').text(name1);
    $('#mat').text(matricule1);
    $('#sal').text(salary1);

    $("#form1").hide();
    $("#form2").show();
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="form1">
  <div class="form-group col-md-3">
    <select class="form-control">
      <option value="imad-22-6000">imad 22 6000</option>
      <option value="gupta-24-8000">gupta 24 8000</option>
      <option value="ganesh-27-5000">ganesh 27 5000</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group col-md-offset-5 ">
    <button class="btn btn-success " id="hide">valider</button>
  </div>
</div>

<!--form 2-->
<div id="form2">
  <h4>name : <span id="nam"></span></h4>
  <h4>matricule : <span id="mat"></span></h4>
  <h4>salary : <span id="sal"></span></h4>
</div>
```